# Adding number format options

Tags: java

I am trying to add the integer commas($40,000 vs $40000 ) into this basic program for the `int` variable.

I am currently using them in the `system.out.println()`.

is there a way to implement it earlier or smoother?

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Employee {

private String name;
private int salary;
private int bonus;

public Employee(String theirName, int theirSalary, int plusBonus) {
    name = theirName;
    salary = theirSalary;
    bonus = plusBonus;
}

public String gettheirname() {
    return name;}

public int gettheirSalary() {
    return salary;}

public int getplusBonus() {
    return bonus;}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e1 = new Employee("Liberty Zapata", 40000, 500);
    System.out.println("ZIG Payroll");
    System.out.println("\t-----------\t Employee \t-----------\t");
    System.out.println("Employee name:" + e1.gettheirname());
    System.out.println( "Salary before bonus: $" + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format((e1.gettheirSalary())));
    System.out.println("Bonus: $" +e1.getplusBonus());
    System.out.println("Salary plus bonus: $" + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format((e1.getplusBonus()+ e1.gettheirSalary()))) ;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can add to class `Employee` a `toString` representation and use it, for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return
            "Employee name:" + name + "\n" +
            "Salary before bonus: $" + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(salary) + "\n" +
            "Bonus: $" + bonus + "\n" +
            "Salary plus bonus: $" + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(bonus + salary);
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e1 = new Employee("Liberty Zapata", 40000, 500);
    System.out.println("ZIG Payroll");
    System.out.println("\t-----------\t Employee \t-----------\t");
    System.out.println(e1) ; // <--- here, now it's simple!
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ZIG Payroll
    -----------  Employee   ----------- 
Employee name:Liberty Zapata
Salary before bonus: $40,000
Bonus: $500
Salary plus bonus: $40,500
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! how does the @Override work here?

Comment: @HMartinez the `@Override` annotation simply instructs the constructor that this method is overriding a method in a parent class (`Object` in our case). It's meant to keep you from shooting your on foot: in case you're using this annotation unjustifiably (for example, the parent's method has a different signature), the compiler will fail and provide a clear error message.